# Dictionary looping on values per key

Tags: excel, vba, date, dictionary

I have the code below to create a dictionary and assign values from
3 columns (i,1) key, and array of dates from `getdates()` from `startdate(i,2)` and `enddate(i,3)`.

My goal is to print each date by key (there can be multiple dates for 1 key) but the code below is giving me a type mismatch error.

```
Sub Test_Dates()
    Dim TESTWB As Workbook
    Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

    Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")

    Dim Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 2 To TESTWS.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        Dict.Add TESTWS.Cells(i, 1).Value, getDates(TESTWS.Cells(i, 2), TESTWS.Cells(i, 3))  
    Next i

    For Each Key In Dict.Keys
        Dim idate As Variant
        For Each idate In Dict.Items
            Debug.Print idate 'this line is where the error is
        Next idate
    Next Key
End Sub
```

This is get dates function to get array of dates between start and end

```
Function getDates(ByVal StartDate As Date, ByVal EndDate As Date) As Variant
    Dim varDates()      As Date
    Dim lngDateCounter  As Long

    ReDim varDates(0 To CLng(EndDate) - CLng(StartDate))

    For lngDateCounter = LBound(varDates) To UBound(varDates)
        varDates(lngDateCounter) = CDate(StartDate)
        StartDate = CDate(CDbl(StartDate) + 1)
    Next lngDateCounter

    getDates = varDates
End Function
```

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: Each `idate ` is an array, so you cannot return it as a string. In order to test if the code returns correctly up to that point, try `Debug.Print idate(0),idate(UBound(idate))`. In this way it will 'extract' `StartDate` and `EndDate`, but from the array dictionary items...

Comment: hi PEH, type mismatch

Comment: @FaneDuru Debug.Print idate(0),idate(UBound(idate)) that prints the first and last dates but am looking to print all of the dates within the array

Comment: My suggested has been done to only test if the code returns well and it does. Now, what do you mean by returning of each date? Do you only want showing them in Immediate window?

Comment: ok yes, in fact i just realised i was missing another for each loop on idate itself, that has solved my issue.

Comment: @Florian you have one loop to much then. See my answer below

Comment: If you declare `Dim varDates` in the function you can simple return: `Debug.Print Join(idate, ", ")`. And using `StartDate = StartDate + 1` should be enough...

Answer (score 3):

Instead of 2 loops through your dictionary you can just use one

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
    Debug.Print Dict.Keys(i),      Join(Dict.Items(i), "|")
Next i
```

alternatively if you need each date as single item, you need 2 loops

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To Dict.Count - 1
    Dim DateItem As Variant
    For Each DateItem in Dict.Items(i)
        Debug.Print Dict.Keys(i),      DateItem 
    Next DateItem
Next i
```

A good source for working with dictionaries: [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Comment: ah yes thanks, that is prob more efficient too

Comment: but in a situation where im not just looking to print the date but use it, how would i use this loop?

Comment: @Florian see my edit. You need 2 loops then but not 3

Answer (score 3):

### Looping Through the Items of a Dictionary

- Check out these two dictionary resources:

  - [Dictionary object (MS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object)
  - [Excel VBA Dictionary (Excel Macro Mastery)](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

To loop through each item of a dictionary and concatenate the elements of the item's array use:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
For Each Arr In Dict.Items
    Debug.Print Join(Arr, ", ")
Next Arr
```

To loop through each element of a dictionary containing zero-based arrays use:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Long
For Each Arr in Dict.Items
    For i = 0 To Ubound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(i)
    Next i
Next Arr
```

Alternatively, use a double `For...Each` loop:

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim Item As Long
For Each Arr in Dict.Items
    For Each Item in Arr
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item
Next Arr
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding another loop on idate does the trick:

```
For Each Key In Dict.Keys

    Dim idate As Variant

    For Each idate In Dict.Items

        Dim bdate As Variant
        
        For Each bdate In idate
        
        Debug.Print bdate
    
        Next bdate
    Next idate
Next Key
```

Comment: Thats one loop too much.